# Using assignment operator with vector of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, memory, vector, std

If I have a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` and resize it, and wanted to add element by index, what is the best way to add them using `operator=`?

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>> _v;
_v.resize(100);
// is it safe to use the assignment operator? 
_v[20] = new item;
```

Comment: Do you think there are many ways to choose from?

Comment: most tutorial talk about using ways to use unique_ptr and ways to avoid just making sure there is no drawback with the = operator.

Comment: Be careful with preceding underscores. They are often reserved for use by the library implementation.
 Handy reading: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @MoradMohammad As mentioned in the answers, there is a drawback for using the assignment operator in a way that you show in your example: [it doesn't compile](https://ideone.com/7OXVw7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) if you are using C++14, like that

```
_v[20] = std::make_unique<item>(/* Args */);
```

Otherwise if you are under C++14, you can make your own implementation of `std::make_unique`, or use the constructor of `std::unique_ptr`

```
_v[20] = std::unique_ptr<item>(new item(/* Args */));
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique_ptr` does not have an assignment operator that takes a raw pointer.

But it does have an assignment operator that moves from another `std::unique_ptr`, which you can create using `std::make_unique()`:

```
_v[20] = std::make_unique<item>();
```

Comment: Note that `std::make_unique()` was added in C++14. For C++11, you can use `_v[20] = std::unique_ptr<item>(new item);` instead.